# Scroll to bottom of ScrollView on iOS using Appcelerator

Tags: ios, scrollview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm looking to perform quite a simple task using Appcelerator, to send my user to the bottom of a scroll view after they have posted a message.

So, inside my scroll view is a simple tableview.

At the top is a post box, where can type a message, and on submit the comment gets posted to our API and the view refreshes. However, my client would like the user to be scrolled to the bottom of the view, as this is where the latest comment is posted (a bit like Facebook).

I can't see to get the content height, it is just returning 'auto' when I try and get it using `scrollView.getContentHeight();`

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

My scrollView is this:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
contentHeight:'auto',
layout:'vertical',
top:60
});
```

What I need to do, is calculate the height of the scrollview and then, if i'm right, set the contentOffset of the scroll view to the height, in order to get it to scroll to the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated!

Simon

Comment: I don't place it as an answer because it is a little hackish, the scrollview has a method [scrollToBottom](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-method-scrollToBottom), but on iOS I always needed to call it twice, with only a call the view will scroll only to the element before the last one; it is probably a good step in the correct direction, but something more correct will be a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't appear to work. Going to have a look at a second call, it may have to do for now until I can find a proper solution!

Comment: If it's a bug, you can file a jira ticket here: https://jira.appcelerator.org